# Boost lib error in using odeint

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I downloaded odeint-v2 in a folder called C++.
I created a new cpp file called HARMONIC.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

std::vector<double> state_type;
double gam = 0.15;

void harmonic_oscillator( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double )
{
    dxdt[0] = x[1];
    dxdt[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

    state_type x(2);
    x[0] = 1.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;


    size_t steps = integrate( harmonic_oscillator, x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.1 );
}
```

While compiling in ubuntu
g++ HARMONIC.cpp -o har.output

The error is as following`

HARMONIC.cpp:4:36: fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

But i downloaded in the same folder all the odeint-v2.

Please help me

Comment: Have you downloaded Boost ?

Comment: What's the path to odeint.hpp? It has to be the same as you specified in the include statement.

Comment: @dshepherd S sir,,the folder which i downloaded is odeintv2/include/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp    
My directory in command window is C++
I downloaded the odeint-v2 into C++

Thanks ,,,
and i created the prog named HARMONIC.cpp

Comment: @PiotrS.
i did like this
g++ clone https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2.git
and a folder named odeint-v2 appeared and i was able to see boost path too

Comment: @Genash Delli: can you print out your folder struct in question?

Comment: Desktop/Ganni/C++/ODEINT/odeint-v2/include/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp
is boosting library
My HARMONIC.cpp is at
Desktop/Ganni/C++/ODEINT/HARMONIC.cpp
My cd is Desktop/Ganni/C++/ODEINT/

And i did like this g++ HARMONIC.cpp -o har.output

Comment: Basically, you need to specify include path in your compiler's command: `g++ HARMONIC.cpp -o har.output -I/path/to/where/boost/is`

Comment: @PiotrS.i did g++ HARMONIC.cpp -o har.output -I/odeint-v2
HARMONIC.cpp:4:36: fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: nah... is /odeint a path in you linux file-system ? put an absolute path

Comment: @PiotrS.  I am not getting you,,,please explain thanks

Comment: say I have downloaded boost to `/home/piotr/myincludes/boost`, whenever I compile something that has `#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>` I use `g++ file.cpp -I/home/piotr/myincludes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different issues going on here.

1. You seem confused about what the library does and where you get it from.  By far the easiest route is to install the Ubuntu boost packages via `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`.
2. The example you copied was missing a critical `typedef`; else `state_type` is not defined.  This has been fixed.
3. I added a simple 'Done' statement at the end.
4. With that, it all just works.

Demo:

```
/tmp$ g++ -o boost_ode boost_ode.cpp 
/tmp$ ./boost_ode 
Done.
/tmp$
```

The repaired code is below.

```
/tmp$ cat boost_ode.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef std::vector<double> state_type;
double gam = 0.15;

void harmonic_oscillator( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double )
{
    dxdt[0] = x[1];
    dxdt[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

    state_type x(2);
    x[0] = 1.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;


    size_t steps = integrate( harmonic_oscillator, x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.1 );

    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
}
/tmp$
```

Comment: T3400:~/Desktop/Ganni/C++/ODEINT$ g++ boost_ode.cpp -o boost.output

boost_ode.cpp:3:36: fatal error: boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I am sorry @Dirk
I am getting the same above....i saved the code as boost_ode of yours and tried to run the same

Comment: Re-read my answer and look at point 1.  So far you made a lot of people spin their wheels but have not actually confirmed that you installed Boost.

Comment: can you please help on this,,,i installed libboost,,it was showing like  libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

Comment: Which boost version is it? odeint is part of boost since 1.53.

Comment: @headmyshoulder IT IS s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.48.0.2

Comment: Thats to old, you need at least 1.53. You can also use odeint-v2 from github,. You need to put odeint-v2/include in your include path. Compile with -Iodeint-v2/include .

Comment: g++ -I/odeint-v2/include boost_ode.cpp -o boost.output
i did the above,,same error again,,,do i need to change in the coding also #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp> to #include <odeint-v2/include/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
How can i compile now,,,i am not able to update,,,Please help me in this issue,,to run the code,,itz really important

Comment: git clone https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2.git
i did the above and i got a folder named odeint-v2;
Now what should i do,,,

Comment: Try -Iodeint-v2/include instead of -I/odeint-v2/include . The path from where you compile must contain the odeint-v2 directory.

Comment: Thanks it worked,,,all the i need to do the same,,,defining path as you said -Iodeint-v2/include;;;;this worked will all the examples work or i need to upgrade to 1.54 version,,i m trying but i m not finding the solution

Comment: I think all examples will work. Nevertheless, I would recommand to update your boost installation. You can easily use boost locally, so you do not need to install it. Simply download the newest version, extract it and specify the include path -I/path/to/boost .

Comment: If you upgrade your Ubuntu version -- which generally works without a hitch and is recommended -- then you get Boost 1.54 'for free'.

Comment: Thank u my version is ubuntu 12.04...i will update and try,,,thanks alot @headmyshoulder and Dirk for ur assistance,,,